# Асинхронные запросы VK SDK Windows Phone

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, windows-phone-8, асинхронность

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Мне необходимо получить список комментариев к последним n постам.
Для этого сначала я запрашиваю список n постов при помощи функции:

```
public async Task<VKList<VKWallPost>> GetLastPosts(int postsCount) //Получаем список последних постов на стене
    {
        var requestResponce = (await VKRequest.Dispatch<VKList<VKWallPost>>(
            new VKRequestParameters(
                "wall.get",
                "count", postsCount.ToString()),
            res =>
            {
            }).DispatchAsync<VKList<VKWallPost>>());
        return requestResponce.ResultCode == VKResultCode.Succeeded ? requestResponce.Data : null;
    }
```

После чего в цикле foreach прохожу по этим постам и по id каждого поста запрашиваю к нему комментарии:

```
public async Task<List<VKComment>> GetUsersCommentedWall(VKList<VKWallPost> lastPosts)
    {
        var result = new List<VKComment>();
        foreach (var post in lastPosts.items)
        {
            var comments = await GetLastPostComments(post.id.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (comments != null && comments.items.Count > 0)
            {
                result.AddRange(comments.items);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Функция, которая возвращает список комментариев к посту по id:

```
        private async Task<VKList<VKComment>> GetLastPostComments(string id) //получаем список комментов к посту
    {
        var requestResponce = (await VKRequest.Dispatch<VKList<VKComment>>(
            new VKRequestParameters(
                "wall.getComments",
                "post_id", id,
                "extended", "1"),
            res =>
            {
            }).DispatchAsync<VKList<VKComment>>());
        return requestResponce.ResultCode == VKResultCode.Succeeded ? requestResponce.Data : null;
    }
```

Когда запрашиваются комментарии только по одному посту, все работает прекрасно, но как только это все производится для 20 постов последняя функция GetLastPostComments() возвращает null, т.к. в ResultCode == TooManyRequestsPerSecond. Как обойти эту проблему? В примерах нет рекомендаций по асинхронным запросам. Выполнять все синхронно? Как не блочить UI?

Comment: Ну так зачем в цикле фигачить обращение к `API` ? Сами как думаете? Делайте человеческий запрос через `execute` используя апишные переменные которые начинаются с `@` и тогда будет вам счастье

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, А можно пример запроса через execute и переменные с @? Про последние первый раз слышу. В примерах про них ни слова. И чем плох async await? Это ж современная практика. Короче, мне нужен только примерчик.

Comment: на счет `async await` не знаю. Но плохо то, что ты в цикле пытаешься запросы совершить, их у тебя можнт быть 1000. А ограничение АПИ - 3 запроса в секунду. Да и вообще запросы в цикле - плохая практика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, вроде вот так работает:

```
var owner_id = 1;

var wall = API.wall.get({owner_id: owner_id });
var wallIds = wall.items@.id;
var i = 0;
var response = {};

while (i < wall.items@.id.length) { 
    response.push({wall:wall.items[i], commentsArr: API.wall.getComments({owner_id: owner_id, post_id: wallIds[i], extended:1})});
    i = i + 1;
};

return {response: response};
```

Где `owner_id`  подставляешь `id` владельца стены. 
Сейчас стоит айдишник Пакла Дурова =D

В итоге получишь массив с полями `wall` и `commentsArr`, в которых лежит инфа по стене и комментам к ней

Пришлось правда внутри использовать цикл, пока по-другому не придумал лучшего ничего(внутри запроса апи поддерживает цикл(**!**)) НО(!!!) желательно использовать именно такие переменные, которые поддерживает АПИ. А не в цикле фигачить множество запросов.

А почитать об `execute` можно [ТУТ](http://vk.com/dev/execute)

Там же можешь скопировать мой код и попробовать.. на примере своей стены

P.S. Вообще, чтобы избежать запросов в цикле можно пойти минимум двумя путями:

**1)** Грамотно сделать запрос в `execute`

**2)** Выбрать все `wall`, выбрать все `comments` в диапазоне выбираемых walls

И потом в цикле уже совместить один массив с другим. Как это часто бывает делают

Если без цикла никак. То использовать цикл внутри запроса `апи`, как он позволяет

Comment: А как в шарпе мне теперь вызвать этот метод и получить сами комменты?

Comment: Всё просто класс, но я так и не понял как запускать из шарпа эти хранимые процедуры и обрабатывать полученный результат. А так переписал уже пару своих методов на хранимых процедурах. И они вообще огонь:)

Comment: @AstemirAlmov не совсем то. Там есть хранимые процедуры, а есть запросы с использованием `execute`. Это две разные вещи. Хранимые процедуры хранятся на стороне `vk`, так сказать, а `execute` методы, это точно такие же запросы как и остальные, Т.е. вместо запроса `https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=1;` будет `https://api.vk.com/method/execute?code="HERE_IS_EXECUTE_CODE"`, где **HERE_IS_EXECUTE_CODE** такой код, что я написал выше. он записывается как строка в кавычках. Но хранимые процедуры тоже вещь)

Comment: Запрос будет что-то типа такого наверное: `new VKRequestParameters(
                "execute",
                "code", "HERE_IS_EXECUTE_CODE") ...`. где `execute` - метод, `code` параметр, `HERE_IS_EXECUTE_CODE` - значение параметра code

Comment: А я запихнул Ваш код в хранимую процедуру и вызвал его как в последнем комменте и все заработало. Правда придется парсить результат запроса. Но раз иначе никак.

Comment: @Astemir Almov это вариант. главное о нем потом не забыть)) Использование хранимых процедур рекомендовано для мобильных приложений с целью экономии трафика.. Просто бывает `execute` полезно выполнять именно у себя. А так - вы вольны выбирать где вам и как лучше делать))

Comment: А чем выгоднее выполнять execute у себя?

Comment: @AstemirAlmov Да не то, чтобы выгодно. Просто если `execute` не является большим, не сложный, то почему бы не исполнить у себя. Да и меньше парсинга потом лишнего и проще переменные передавать, составлять запрос. А если запрос большой, сложный, или есть вероятность выполнения его продолжительное время - то возможно конечно стоит разгрузить приложение и в хранимой процедуре все сделать. Но это лишь мое мнение)