# Не могу преодолеть VkAPIError: 6. Too many requests per second

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, python-3.x

Такой вот код. Собирает все посты группы. Что я делаю не так?

```
owner_id = ID
wall = []
count = self.api.wall.get(owner_id=owner_id)[0]
offset = 0
while offset < count:
    got = False
    while not got:
        try:
            code = 'var wall;'\
                    'wall = API.wall.get'\
                    '({"owner_id":%s,'\
                    '"offset":%s,'\
                    '"count":%s});'\
                    'return wall;' % (owner_id,
                                      offset,
                                      101)
            part_wall = self.api('execute', code=code)[1:]
            offset += len(part_wall)
            got = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            sleep(1)
    wall.extend(part_wall)
```

Comment: А разве не ясно из ошибки? Слишком дофига обращений к апи в секунду. Что тут непонятного? Разрешено 3 обращения в секунду. А вы в цикле фигачите.

Comment: Ошибка понятна, в случае исключения даю "поспать" 1 секунду. К тому же метод execute разрешает до 25 обращений в секунду - а оно валится уже после первого запроса.

Comment: так в случае исключения вроде бы заканчивается вообще всякая работа? Разве нет? Хоть вы на сутки спать оставьте. Вам надо либо 1) sleep  делать не в exception, а сразу после исполнения одного запроса 2) сделать человеческий запрос а не ддос атаку..... а по поводу `execute` -> `Внутри code может содержаться не более 25 обращений к методам API.` а не сам метод позволяет обратиться 25 раз в секуну, это **БОЛЬШАЯ** разница

Comment: Так может дело в том что он считает не только от вас обращения? Например айпишник один. Сам то код работает, или нет? (за вычетом сна)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, не заканчивается. Я раньше делал простые запросы и после sleep() продолжало всё работать. А насчёт code - спасибо за разъяснение, сам себя ввёл в заблуждение)

Comment: @GriMel Что самое смешное, внутри `execute` можно сделать этот самый цикл и `API` это проглотит и не подавится. пример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468568/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-vk-sdk-windows-phone/468616#468616

Comment: Интересно, но вот теперь почему-то не срастается у меня с фильтрами - `code = "var wall; wall = API.wall.get({owner_id: 1});
return wall.items@.id;"` возвращает почему-то пустой массив. Пробовал код [здесь](http://vk.com/dev/execute). Не подскажете, что я делаю не так?)

Comment: @GriMel Да вроде все возвращается [ТЫК](http://s017.radikal.ru/i405/1512/d4/bf5fe32898b1.jpg) или пустой массив именно в вашем коде получается?

Comment: Пустой массив в моем коде. Ну тоесть `w = api('execute', code=code)` и потом `print(w)` выводит `[]`

Comment: Разобрался. При инициализации vk api нужно было передать параметр '5.4' для v=. По умолчанию версия 3.0 используется, которая на такой запрос как раз ничего и не возвращает.

Comment: @GriMel Если вы разобрались с проблемой, будет полезно написать ответ на свой же вопрос. Так вы сможете помочь и другим людям, столкнувшимся с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При инициализации vk api нужно было передать параметр '5.4' для v=. По умолчанию версия 3.0 используется. Это решило проблему.