# Ошибка Bad method name при использовании VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, python-3.x

Чтоб не забивать комментарии [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471213/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-vkapierror-6-too-many-requests-per-second?noredirect=1#comment528125_471213), решил создать новый вопрос

Собираю все посты группы, наверное ошибка в коде.

Вот кусок кода

```
code = r"var wall, part_wall;"\
           "var offset = %s;"\
           "var count = 100;"\
           "while (offset <= 2500)"\
           "{"\
           "part_wall = API.wall.get({owner_id: %s, count: count, offset: offset});"\
           "offset  += count;"\
           "part_wall = part_wall.items@.id;"\
           "wall.concat(part_wall);"\
           "};"\
           "return wall;" % (group_id, offset)
```

И запрос

```
part_wall = self.api('execute', code=code)
```

В общем, код с циклом и sleep(), из part_wall собирается полный массив wall.

При первом же запросе выбивает исключение (не показываю id группы, поставил id Дурова)

> vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 13. Runtime error occurred during code invocation: Bad method name. request_params = {'count': '100', 'owner_id': '1', 'offset': '0'}

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что внутри `execute` контактовское `API` поддерживает не все операции, доступные на `javascript`.

Что конкретно поддерживает можно посмотреть [ТУТ](http://vk.com/dev/execute)

Поэтому порой вместо простых решений приходится извратиться

В данном случае ругается на `wall.concat`

Кстати, по идее конструкции типа `offset  += count` тоже не поддерживаются и `API` должен был изначально на нее поругаться. Вместо нее должен работать старый способ `offset = offset + count`. Странно, что не выдал ошибку на этом моменте

Comment: заменил concat push-ем и потом `temp = [] for i in wall: temp.extend(i)`
Да и `+=` тоже выбивает ошибку, вы правы.